# AWS CLI describe-snapshots to print SnapshotId

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, jmespath

I am trying to print the SnapshotId for the newest snapshot using bash. Here is my command:

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots | grep TestVolume1 |head -n 1| > Output.txt
```

Above result matches TestVolume1 to write to Output.txt the newest snapshot. I also want to print the SnapshotID and am struggling to output that to Output.txt.

I have tried `awk` and `--filter` and that does not help. Would appreciate any help with syntax to output `SnapshotId`. What else can I use?

Comment: Are you simply wanting to obtain the SnapshotId for the most-recently created snapshot? What is the purpose of `TestVolume1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `--filter` argument to retrieve only the matched snapshots and use `--query` argument to parse the required field from the response,

**Update** (adding reverse sort of snapshots based on snapshot start time):

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --filters Name=description,Values="*TestVolume1*" --query "reverse(sort_by(Snapshots, &StartTime))[0].SnapshotId"
```

The filter is applied on the description of the snapshot expecting it to contain the desired text (`TestVolume1`).

Comment: If this doesn't always give the "newest" snapshot, you can use a `sort_by()` in the `--query` and return the first/last element. See: [JMESPath Examples — JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/examples.html)

Comment: Thanks for replying. Apparently my --query does not work and don't have any Tags. Here is the error: zsh: command not found: --query

Comment: What is `TestVolume1` part of? Snapshot description?

Comment: Hi - is one of the volume names. We have snapshots occurring for each EBS volume through out the day (i.e TestVolume1,TestVolume2 etc..). My goal is to extract the newest snapshot for a Volume and restore that snapshot based on SnapshotId hence the need for printing the SnapshotId.

Comment: I assume that the you have added the VolumeName information in the description of the Snapshot! Check the updated answer

Comment: Thank you! That updated command worked. Appreciate your insight ands guidance.

Comment: Okay I though I would be able to figure this out but How would I run this command for multiple volumes? I want to find the newest snapshot for the many volumes that I have. (TestVolume1 - TestVolume10)

Comment: @NetSystemAdmin That would require running this command multiple times. You can try with a for loop, `for i in {1..10}; do aws ec2 describe-snapshots --filters Name=description,Values="*TestVolume$i*" --query "reverse(sort_by(Snapshots, &StartTime))[0].SnapshotId" >> snapshots.txt; done`

Comment: Hi - that worked thank you so much!! You have been super helpful. I also increased for loop to {1..20} because I needed to print all the snapshotsIds. I have many volumes and am able to see many of the snapshotIds now.  If I wanted to output more than SnapshotId, let's say VolumeSize or State, would I add to the filters section? I was going to try that out.

Comment: No, add to the `--query` section.